# StructureMap - Don't Expect Same Object

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am using structuremap in my C# application and getting behaviour that I don't understand or expect.  Hopefully someone can explain either what I'm doing wrong or why my expectation is incorrect!

When a constructor takes two arguments of the same type, I expect them to be separate instances of the same type - not references to the same instance.  Sample app below demonstrates this.

Registry: (not does not use Singleton()

```
    public class DemoRegistry: Registry
    {
        public DemoRegistry()
        {
            For<IController>().Use<Controller>();
            For<IAnInterface>().Use<AClass>();
        }
    }
```

My injected types:

```
public interface IAnInterface { }

public class AClass : IAnInterface {}
```

The class that illustrates the issue (I don't expect obj1 to be equal to obj2):

```
public interface IController {}

public class Controller : IController
{
    private readonly IAnInterface _obj1;
    private readonly IAnInterface _obj2;

    public Controller(IAnInterface obj1, IAnInterface obj2)
    {
        _obj1 = obj1;
        _obj2 = obj2;
        bool sameObject = ob1 == obj2; // this is TRUE
    }
}
```

And finally the Main method to run it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<DemoRegistry>());
        IController c = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IController>();
    }
```

I'm using .Net 4.0 and StructureMap 2.5.4.

So to summarise:

- Why does obj1 == obj2 in sample above?

Hopefully this is clear, I'm happy to provide further information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new instance every time an instance of a type is needed, use the [unique lifetime](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/07/20/StructureMapPerRequestvs.Uniquelifetimes/).

```
var unique = new UniquePerRequestLifecycle();
x.For<IAnInterface>().LifecycleIs(unique).Use<AClass>();
```

Comment: Thanks @georg.  I will try this in the morning and accept if it works. Not sure I understand why this is needed, my understanding of Structure map DSL is it says "if you get asked for one of these,  then instantiate one of those". Unless of course I had used For <IAnInterface>.Singleton ().Use <AClass>()